# Definition of current capacity of a voltaic cell

Tags: current, batteries, education

I'm looking for the definition of current capacity of a voltaic cell, but online I found only sentences in which this locution was used without a definiton.

Can you tell me what is the definition please?

---

EDIT: I read the locution [here](https://www.oakton.edu/user/1/agero/elt101/presentations/Chapter12.pdf):

[image]

Comment: Can you explain me the downvote please? Is anything not clear?

Comment: Your question got a vote to close (not by me) due to the requirement of details and clarity.

Comment: Hello @RohatKılıç thank you for your suggestion; I edited the question.

Comment: I'm not an expert in voltaic cells, but I would suggest you read up on what differences there are in a high drain versus high capacity batteries. High current = thick electrodes are needed to minimize ohmic losses.

Comment: It means "the amount of current you can get". Don't overthink it

Comment: Thank you for your useful comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current capacity of any power source is the maximum current you can draw from the source while the voltage remains within certain bounds. What those bounds are doesn't matter when doing relative comparisons - all that matters is that they remain the same.

So, when they say "they current capacity increases with large electrode size", they mean that:

1. You choose some maximum allowed voltage drop from nominal output voltage that you consider acceptable.
2. You draw progressively higher current from cell A until that threshold is reached. Record that current and call it "current capacity of cell A".
3. Then draw progressively higher current from cell B until the threshold voltage you chose is reached. Record that current and it's "current capacity of cell B".
4. If cell B has larger electrodes than cell A, you should expect cell B's current capacity to be larger than cell A, under identical conditions otherwise.

The "otherwise identical conditions" means that the cells are fully charged and thus have same cell voltage, are at the same temperature, etc.

Comment: Hello @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica thank you very much for your answer. Do you have a book/handout where you met the locution "current capacity"? If yes, can you tell me the title/the professor please?